# Is any variable in PostgreSQL to store a list

Tags: python, postgresql

We have a ticket software to manage our work, every ticket is assigned to a tech in one field -the normal stuff-, but now we want to assign the same ticket to several technicians eg: tick 5432: tech_id(2,4,7) where 2,4,7 are tech IDs.

Of course we can do that using a separate table with the IDs of the tech and the ticket ID, but we have to convert the data.

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way to do this is to have a separate table of ticket
assignments. Converting the data for something like this is fairly simple on the database end.  `create table assign as select tech_id from ...` followed by creating any necessary foreign key constraints.
Rewriting your interface code can be trickier, but you're going to
have to do that anyway to allow for more than one tech.

You could use an array type, but sometimes database
interfaces don't understand postgres array types.  There isn't anything
inherent in arrays that prevents duplicates or imposes ordering, but
you could do that with an appropriate trigger.

Comment: We try array type and it worked fine. we don't use any database interface, but the problem was in the query how to show the names of the tech, a separate table will easier to maintain the code.